# Does logcat log errors that are 12 hours old?

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-4.4-kitkat, reboot

This morning my Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3 (Android 4.4.2) rebooted suddenly. I was not doing anything at that time, and it was the very first time when it did that.
I managed to pull out a logcat using adb, but about 11 hours later. Also, I don't think that logcat was enabled on my phone at the time when the error occurred. Is there a way to see an error that is 12 hours long?

I suspect that the phone rebooted due to a system update. Is there a way to see a system update history, perhaps using an app instead of a code? I need the EXACT time (date + hour) of the last update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, I don't think that logcat was enabled on my phone at the time when the error occurred

Logging is always enabled. LogCat simply reports what's in the log.

> Is there a way to see an error that is 12 hours long?

The logging area is a ring buffer. It used to be fixed at 64KB. On Android 5.0, it is selectable by you via the Developer Options in the Settings app. I am not sure how big it is on Android 4.4 in general, let alone on a Samsung device.

How old the logs can be therefore is dependent on the size of the ring buffer and how much stuff gets logged. Unfortunately, production hardware logs a lot, so I would be skeptical that you can see 12+ hours back in the log. For example, on my Nexus 5, in a 256KB log buffer, I get about 8 hours of history.

> Is there a way to see a system update history, perhaps using an app instead of a code?

Not that I am aware of, though that would be a better question for [the Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I checked, and I get about 1024KB on /dev/log/main, and 512KB on /dev/log/system. Any chance to see errors older than 11 hours? Also, how do I identify reboots in the logcat?

Comment: @LucreziavanNecker: "Any chance to see errors older than 11 hours?" -- again, it depends on the size of the buffer and the amount of logging. "Also, how do I identify reboots in the logcat?" -- beats me. I have never tried identifying a reboot. You might scan for signs of the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast going out.

Comment: I pulled the logcat to a .txt file, but there is no date or time of ANY of the events (and this is VERY important). I need the timestamp; how can I get it? Also, can I differentiate user-initiated reboots and system reboots? I noticed `completed_sys.boot_completed` in the logcat.

Comment: @LucreziavanNecker: For timestamps, `adb logcat -v threadtime`. "Also, can I differentiate user-initiated reboots and system reboots?" -- I have no idea.

Comment: @LucreziavanNecker: Sorry, but have no idea if that's possible, let alone how to do it.

Comment: One more question: If I revert the phone to an earlier date, is there a chance that the software update I mentioned will not show up any more? I want to basically reproduce the entire reboot thing - and if I revert the phone to an earlier state, perhaps the update will later occur, so the phone will reboot. But I will make sure to prevent losing logcat files before that.

Comment: @LucreziavanNecker: "If I revert the phone to an earlier date, is there a chance that the software update I mentioned will not show up any more?" -- you would have to ask Samsung for an official statement. However, I expect that they will detect that you are on the updated software and not attempt updating it again, regardless of dates.